# Учебные пособия по Visual C++ и C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, visual-studio, c++

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, учебные пособия по Visual C++, C++Builder, которые помогут понять их по максимуму.

Answer (score 1):

Visual C++ 2010 Пахомов, сам читаю, вполне нравится, есть еще книга Хортона на эту тему, но пока не купил, не скажу какая + МСДН , ничего лучше вам не найти.

Builder c++ 2010  тут ответ, на мой взгляд, еще легче - Архангельский, книга прямо так и называется

Answer (score 1):

А по Visual C++ -- Герберт Шилдт -- идеальное решение. Можно ещё Страуструпа прочитать, как родителя языка, но он сложнее...

Answer (score 0):

По С билдеру однозначно начинать с Архангельского. Очень понятно и наиболее полно.